# Running 2 timers from 1 timestamp and displaying correctly

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I need some help to get my game-timers up and running. I can't get them both running together showing both the correct value.

**Timer 1:**
When a player presses "Start" the current `DateTime` get send to a database. The gametime is that timestamp + 2 hours. The first timer indicates how many time is left since pressing the startbutton, so it's running down from "2:00:00" until "0:00:00". When this timer is finished, the game is over.

**Timer 2:**
I also need a timer that runs along with the other timer(or do I have to use the same timer?) that starts at "0:15:00" and runs exactly 15 minutes. That timer sends something to a database when the 15 minutes are elapsed, and then gets restarted at "0:00:00" and does this until the gametime is finished.

This is the code I'm using at the moment. I know... it's no very neat, first time using these timers and couldn't come up with anything better.

```
    Timer gameTimer;

    DateTime gameEndTime;

    int updateTime;
    int fifteenMinutes = (((100 * 10) * 60) * 15);

    private void GameTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan tsGameTime = gameEndTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

        updateTime += 100;
        if (updateTime == (fifteenMinutes - 100))
        {
            updateTime = 0;
        }
        TimeSpan tsUpdateTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(fifteenMinutes - updateTime);

        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            txtGameTime.Text = string.Format("Time till next game: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", tsGameTime);
            txtLocationTime.Text = string.Format("Time till update: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", tsUpdateTime);
        });
    }
```

Now I can't get these timers run exactly at the same amount of time like:

Timer 1: "1:44:59"
Timer 2: "0:00:01"

Always timer 2 stays a couple of milliseconds behind after restarting, and after a few restarts timer 2 is behind even more than a second. So again, do I need 1 central timer, and update both `TextView` in the same `Elapsed` events? Or do I need 2 seperate timers?

Comment: how is this "(((100 * 10) * 60) * 1)" equal to 15 minutes?  And if you have two separate timers running independently they are never going to be in perfect sync.  Either ignore the small discrepancy, or use one master timer for both functions.

Comment: @Jason I edited it to 1 minute because of testing, didn't want to wait 15 minutes to see if it worked, will edit the post, sorry. And ok 1 timer, as you see I'm using one timer in my post but still won't manage to get it show correctly.

Comment: it may just be a rounding error.  Since you only need a 1s resolution, I'd try discarding anything smaller than that when you get the current time, and then base all of your calculations off of that value

Comment: @Jason I don't think I understand what you are saying? I'm discarding by 100 miliseconds? Can you please show me an example?